# How to make a Rollover Image but, it stays as that image when pressed in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have a normal rollover image as so...

```
'MainMenuTab
Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.Click
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage1
End Sub

'MainMenuTab Down
Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.MouseEnter
    MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Down
End Sub

'MainMenuTab Up
Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.MouseLeave
    MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Norm
End Sub
```

So I have my Mouse 'Enter' and 'Leave', but what I have been trying to do is make the image change when pressed to "MainMenuTab_Selected.jpg" but then it changes the image back to "MainMenuTab_Norm.png" because the mouse is leaving the Picture Box.

So Is there a way to use 'If' statements, because that is what I have been looking at. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a variable when you click the button, and then check the value of it on the mouse events:

```
Dim buttonClicked as Boolean = False
Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.Click
    MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Selected
    buttonClicked = True
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage1
End Sub

'MainMenuTab Down
Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.MouseEnter
    If Not buttonClicked Then
        MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Down
    End If
End Sub

'MainMenuTab Up
Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.MouseLeave
    If Not buttonClicked Then
        MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Norm
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just the think I was looking for. I know this is another question, but how would I make it so when you start it, it is already on "MainMenuTab_Selected.jpg"? So it is like the default tab you start on?

Comment: You can call the button's associated click function directly in the form's Load method if you wish - although doing so would prevent the user seeing any image changes by mousing over the button. Whether this is intended is up to you.