# How to switch between Images but with a Dim Statement

Tags: vb.net

I have this following code...

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim MMButtonClicked As Boolean = False
Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.Click
    MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Selected
    MMButtonClicked = True
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage1
End Sub
' MainMenuTab Down
Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.MouseEnter
    If Not MMButtonClicked Then
        MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Down
    End If
End Sub
' MainMenuTab Up
Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.MouseLeave
    If Not MMButtonClicked Then
        MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Norm
    End If
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim IbuttonClicked As Boolean = False
Private Sub ItemsTabBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ItemsTabBtn.Click
    ItemsTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.ItemsTab_Selected
    IbuttonClicked = True
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage2
End Sub
' ItemsTab Down
Private Sub ItemsTabBtn_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ItemsTabBtn.MouseEnter
    If Not IbuttonClicked Then
        ItemsTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.ItemsTab_Down
    End If
End Sub
' ItemsTab Up
Private Sub ItemsTabBtn_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ItemsTabBtn.MouseLeave
    If Not IbuttonClicked Then
        ItemsTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.ItemsTab_Norm
    End If
End Sub
```

This is a rollover for MainMenuTabBtn and ItemsTabBtn but when they are clicked they change to "MainMenuTab_Selected.jpg" or "ItemsTab_Selected.jpg" depending on the button. But how do I make it so when ItemsTab is clicked, MainMenuTab will change from "MainMenuTab_Selected.jpg" (its selected state) to "MainMenuTab_Normal.jpg". (which is unselected) but then ItemsTab is selected.

Comment: how is this different from the [version you asked 2 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25406104/1070452)?  How exactly is it that `Dim` is causing a problem?

Comment: I do not know if it was Dim causing the problem. Well, there is not one from the previous question, I made a different question because when I add 2 buttons they both stay as _Selected but I only want 1 selected at a time.

Comment: This is a different question to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406104/how-to-make-a-rollover-image-but-it-stays-as-that-image-when-pressed-in-vb-net I want to know how to do it so when I add another button, they do not both highlight when pressed. (only one can be highlighted at a time)

Comment: Just use a variable eg `Dim WhichBtnSelected as Integer`, where 0 none selected, 1 MainMenuTabBtn selected and 2 ItemsTabBtn selected. You dont need MMButtonClicked or IbuttonClicked.

Comment: I am having trouble with it, is it possible if you could give me an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many buttons as you like. Just change the `WhichBtnSelected` in every button event accordingly.

```
Dim WhichBtnSelected as Integer = 0 'none selected

Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.Click
    If WhichBtnSelected = 1 then
        Return
    End If

    If WhichBtnSelected = 2 then
        ItemsTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.ItemsTab_Norm
    End If

    WhichBtnSelected = 1
    MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Selected
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage1
End Sub

' MainMenuTab Enter
Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.MouseEnter
    If WhichBtnSelected = 1 then
        Return
    End If

    MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Enter
End Sub
' MainMenuTab Down
Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.MouseDown
    If WhichBtnSelected = 1 then
        Return
    End If

    MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Down
End Sub

Private Sub MainMenuTabBtn_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenuTabBtn.MouseLeave
    If WhichBtnSelected = 1 then
        Return
    End If

    MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Norm
End Sub
```

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Private Sub ItemsTabBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ItemsTabBtn.Click
    If WhichBtnSelected = 2 then
        Return
    End If

    If WhichBtnSelected = 1 then
        MainMenuTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Norm
    End If

    WhichBtnSelected = 2

    ItemsTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.ItemsTab_Selected

    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage2
End Sub

' ItemsTab Enter
Private Sub ItemsTabBtn_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ItemsTabBtn.MouseEnter
    If WhichBtnSelected = 2 then
        Return
    End If

    ItemsTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.ItemsTab_Enter
End Sub

' ItemsTab Down
Private Sub ItemsTabBtn_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ItemsTabBtn.MouseDown
    If WhichBtnSelected = 2 then
        Return
    End If

    ItemsTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.ItemsTab_Down
End Sub

Private Sub ItemsTabBtn_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ItemsTabBtn.MouseLeave
    If WhichBtnSelected = 2 then
        Return
    End If

    ItemsTabBtn.Image = My.Resources.ItemsTab_Norm
End Sub
```

When I am trying to make a custom button I am not using a `Button` control but instead a `Label`.

EDIT

If you have eg 5 buttons:

```
Dim bttns(4) As Button
Dim imgs(4) As Image
```

In your form load

```
bttns(0) = MainMenuTabBtn
bttns(1) = ItemsTabBtn
...
bttns(4) = ....

imgs(0) = My.Resources.MainMenuTab_Norm
imgs(1) = My.Resources.ItemsTab_Norm
...
imgs(4) = ....
```

In every button click event substitute the second `If` statement with

```
If WhichBtnSelected <> 0 then
    bttns(WhichBtnSelected - 1).Image = imgs(WhichBtnSelected - 1)
End If
```

Of course you must also change the number depending on the button:

```
If WhichBtnSelected = ? then '1, 2, 3, ...
    Return
End If
```

Valter

Comment: Im having some trouble adding different buttons, I need to add 5 more buttons, does that mean I will have to do `If WhichBtnSelected = 3` and `If WhichBtnSelected = 4` for 2 new buttons? I am have trouble with it and cannot seem to add them without the visuals of the button breaking/messing up.

Comment: @GregRogers Yes. The problem is how to find which button is previously selected so you draw the norm image. You can use the `if else if` statement but that is ugly. Let me think about it.

Comment: Ahh right ok, what is Form Load though? And where is it? Also, do you mind putting it into the code above, because I have a hard time finding where to put it.

Comment: @GregRogers Select your form (in design) and in the properties window select `events`. Double click the `Load` one

Comment: I managed to add more buttons, thank you very much for all of the help you gave me.